# How to provide 2 builds in a single track from google play store?

Tags: android, testing, google-play

I have created 2 builds; 1 is pointing to development servers, and the other is pointing to production servers.

I want to upload both of them in a single track, and I want both to be available from the play store.

Is there any way to achieve this? I can upload 1 build on internal testing track, and another one on alpha track, but a tester can only be part of 1 track at a time, which again becomes a problem..

In iOS we have Apple supported Testflight, which can handle multiple builds at a time. Is something like this achievable from the playstore?

Answer (score 2):

App center is a solution for your question

You can configure the app center to release build for every push to master. You need to create two product flavors one is for development another one is a production

Regarding Product flavors highly recommended going through below link for better understanding

- https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants
- https://www.journaldev.com/21533/android-build-types-product-flavors

Once you successfully configured you need to create two separate apps in App center
You need to configure a separate product flavor for each app and destination in the play store.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to achieve this. Although I can upload 1 build on internal testing track, and another one on alpha track, but a tester can only be part of 1 track at a time, which again become a problem..

Besides the internal testing track and the alpha track, there is also the beta track. So you can have 3 builds simultaneously. So then the only remaining issue is that "a tester can only be part of 1 track at a time". Well, yes and no. "A tester", as in one google account, can be part of 1 track at a time. But a human tester can have multiple google accounts, and these google accounts can be part of different tracks, e.g., 3 tracks (internal, alpha, beta), each with 3 google accounts for that tester.